# Disable page behind a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have a page where someone can click on a button. When the button is clicked I want to open a div and disable the page behind the div? There is a button on that Div which can be clicked to hid this Div.  I am new to Web Programming Development.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and we'll help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create modal box using html, css and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165984/how-to-create-modal-box-using-html-css-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Set the CSS `pointer-events: none;` on the `<body>` element but override it for the `<div>` you want to show.