# Highlight div, and make other things on page darker

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
.slicknav_nav {
    touch-action: pan-y;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 102px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 20%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And, what I want is that when I click on button that makes this div appear, I want this div to be highlighted and others darkened.
Same, as on youtube page, when you click slick menu, its highlighed and other areas darkened.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :). Can you show us your HTML and more of your CSS? Did you try something else yet?

Comment: Hi, and thank you. Yea, I did try jquery lightSwitcher, which I have for my videos on page, but I wonder if this is possible with css, so I don't have to have so many jquery stuff. It is basically slick menu, when i click it, this div will apear with such css.

Comment: Hi, please provide some code snippet. Probably you want something like modal dialog. With pure javascript and css you can see the example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp.

Comment: You want a "modal"? Please see this link on how to create one: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create modal box using html, css and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165984/how-to-create-modal-box-using-html-css-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without proper [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but here is a simplified solution:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('hi-activate');
let tohighlight = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
let allothers = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  for(let i = 0; i < allothers.length; i++){
    allothers[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
    allothers[i].style.background = "#dedede";
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < tohighlight.length; i++){
    tohighlight[i].style.opacity = "1";
    tohighlight[i].style.background = "#98FB98";
    
  }
});
```

```css
div, button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>Some content</div>
<div>Another content</div>
<div class="highlight">Highlightable content</div>
<div>And some more content</div>
<div class="highlight">Also highlightable</div>
<div>And the end</div>

<button id="hi-activate">Click me!</button>
```

To understand what is done, you attach an `EventListener` to the button (or whatever) and upon firing it, you set a certain `style` to to elements, while changing all the rest.

Obviously, to achieve the effect YouTube has, you'll need to do far more styling, but this should serve as a handy illustration on how it is achieved.

Comment: HI, thanks for helping. I tried this https://pastebin.com/3vt4KsCp but ti says Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function and also it should be back clickable as I see your example won't elt me click back to remove highlied divs.

Comment: in your example, you need to change `btn` to `btn[0]` The `getElementsByClassName` selector returns a nodelist (an array-like object), even if it consists only of one item. Also yes, in my example, there's no click-back, but I'm sure you can come up with a way to reverse-engineer a way for that (it's literally just changing the values of the `style` back to their original)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this type of html then You can try below code

```
<div class="slicknav_nav ">
    <div class="entry-content">
         <div class="expose">something</div>
         <div class="expose">something</div>
         <div class="expose">something</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slicknav_nav {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:99998;
    pointer-events:none
}
.expose{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.entry-content').hover(function() {
    $('.slicknav_nav').fadeIn(300);
}, function() {
    $('.slicknav_nav').fadeOut(300);
});

$('.expose').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', '99999');
},function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', '1');
});
```